# result of a function is difference with result of map

Tags: python, function, dictionary

##Why the results of these two ways are different?##

```
my_list = [a, b, c]
def printable(x):return x*3
printable(my_list)
```

with this

```
list(map(printable,my_list)
```

??

Comment: `printable(my_list)` calls the function `printable` *once* with the whole of `my_list` as the parameter.  `list(map(printable,my_list))` calls the function *three times*, once with each element of the list as the parameter, and collects the results in a list.

Comment: Yes, you are doing to very different things, so you receive different results. Multiplying *a list* with a scalar is a different operation as multiplying *each element of a list* with the same scalar.

Comment: if you want to zoom, email me yishai rasowsky at gmail

Answer (score 0):

When the * operator is used on a list, the result is just that list repeated n times. For example,
`[1, 2, 3] * 3 would yield [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

However if you want to multiply each element of the list by a number n, you'd use the second method. The map() function returns a map object(which is an iterator) of the results after applying the given function to each item of a given iterable (list, tuple etc.)

That is why you are getting different results.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for `map`, we can see that it takes `map(function, iterable)` in which it applies the `function` to every item in `iterable`.

In this particular case, it seems like you only want to provide one argument, which just happens to be an iterable itself. So we can wrap your argument with a list as such to get the desired result:

```py
>>> list(map(printable,[my_list]))[0]
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

```py
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> def printable(x):return x*3
>>> printable(my_list)
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```